# wget is not using environment variable based proxy settings

Tags: windows, powershell, proxy, wget, nano-server

I have a windows nano server and try to set the proxy settings. The nano server is only in command mode no GUI. I have run in PowerShell

```
netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="ipadress:8080"
```

then I have

```
ping www.google.de
```

and the IP address from google was shown, so there is some connection. But when I try to run

```
wget www.google.de
```

I get

```
"Unable to connect to the remote server"
```

then I have set the proxy in the PowerShell environment with

```
set http_proxy="ipadress:8080" and https_proxy...
```

but the same problem. When I call wget directly with the proxy settings it works:

```
wget 'http://www.google.de' -Proxy http://ipadress:8080
```

How can I get it work that `wget` uses the global proxy settings? Or are the settings not correctly set? Or need I to install some windows features, that it is working?

I use `wget` to test the connection later any web request for any program should work.

Comment: What did it return when you ran `netsh winhtp set... `? What happend after a restart (to make sure you get a new powershell-session just in case it didn't pick up the new settings)?

Comment: netsh winhttp set -- has return the right proxy configuration in "Proxy Server(s)". I restarted serval times no change.

Comment: How did you run `wget 'http://www.google.de' -Proxy http://ipadress:8080` on a Nano Server? `wget` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` which I don't think is available on Nano Server

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest is available on this nano server build

Answer (score 10):

Pretty sure your issue here is that you are not setting environment variables and getting mixed up between cmd exe's and PowerShell cmdlets. As we read from the (what I hope is) the [documentation for wget concerning proxy information](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Proxies):

> The standard way to specify proxy location, which Wget recognizes, is using the following environment variables:
>
> - http_proxy
> - https_proxy

Which is exactly what you tried to do here which was a successful operation (no error) but did not work as expected.

```
set http_proxy="ipadress:8080"
```

Problem is that if you run that in PowerShell `set` is an alias for `Set-Variable`. See `Get-Alias set`.

```
PS C:\Users\matt> Get-Variable http*

Name                           Value                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                        
http_proxy=ipadress:8080
```

You are also having an issue with `wget` as that is an alias of `Invoke-WebRequest`. That would only be an issue if you had at least PowerShell version 3.0 which you appear to have. In your working example you are using cmdlet syntax (`-Proxy ...`).

In both cases (`set` and the non-working `wget`) the command was ambiguous and PowerShell had to try to match it up to something....

So what we are seeing here is [about_Command_Precedence](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh848304.aspx) coming into play

> If you do not specify a path, Windows PowerShell uses the following precedence order when it runs commands:
>
> 1. Alias
> 2. Function
> 3. Cmdlet
> 4. Native Windows commands

Native Windows commands is *last on the list*! Really though if you are in PowerShell doing this you might as well use PowerShell cmdlets to get your environment variables set (if you insist on using `wget`). The only thing I am not sure of is which method you should use the first here should not persist the session where the second method is permanent. Sure the first would suffice but use the second if you want to keep these set on the computer between sessions.

1. `$env:http_proxy = "ipaddress:8080"`
2. `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("http_proxy", "ipaddress:8080", "Machine")`

You can read [more on this from TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx). Also watch your spelling of "address"

---

If you are going to be using cmd utilities make sure you append .exe and if you don't specify the full path to the resource then ensure its directory is part of the path environment variable.

Comment: @FrodeF. I don't use it enough for that to be in my head. The op might have got the two confused and tab completed something by accident. I think my update covers what the OP was doing... confusing the usage and syntax of both gnu wget and Invoke-Webrequest

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the powershell commandlets the wget what is a shortcut for Invoke-WebRequest can't work with a proxy that needs authentication. It is not the only commandlet wich is not working with proxy's. The easist way was to use the 
[cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/)

set up the proxy and use it as proxy and it is working.